# how to run a perl script in SQL procedure

Tags: sql, database, perl, sql-server-2008

I have a database on SQL server that needs a trigger. I made the trigger but I need to run some Perl scripts when an update,Insert or Delete is found. How can I run a perl script in the SQL Trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Here is MSDN post on same problem: [Call a DLL or EXE file from SQL Trigger](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/688ec345-813e-4028-a7b1-1839e4af9d7b/call-a-dll-or-exe-file-from-sql-trigger)